# Hide columns based on cell text from dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create the code to hide columns E:T based on the value of the text in cell C1, leaving the matching column unhidden. This could work the other way if columns E:T were hidden already, and the matching column to C1 text would unhide.

Cell C1 is a dropdown list with data from E2:T2.

Sorry if this seems a bit vague.

[image: Snip of worksheet]

I found some code but wasn't able to modify it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Workbook_Open` updates data validation list on cell C1 when users open the workbook.

`Worksheet_Change` is tiggered when cell C1 is changed.

```vb
' Save code in ThisWorkbook module
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  With Me.[C2].Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=$E$2:$T$2"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
    End With
End Sub

' Save code in Sheetx module 
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Address = "$C$1" And Len(.Cells(1).Value) > 0 Then
            Set c = Range("E2:T2").Find(.Value, , , xlWhole)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                Columns("E:T").Hidden = True
                Columns(c.Column).Hidden = False
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! Works perfectly. Thank you so much!!